# Show facebook plugins after they're loaded

Tags: facebook, angular, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm making the app in Angular 2 using Typescript. I've implemented some of the facebook's plugins to the page. Now when I'm loading/reloading the page, they're loading so slow and it takes a while after they completely load. They load in parts... so e.g. Facebook Page plugin shows header first, then the rest of the plugin, and so on... it looks ugly in my opinion. Is there a way I can make some listener and show them after they're completely loaded?

Here is the code (index.html with facebook's javascriptSDK):

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>BLOG OLIFFFFFFKA</title>
  <base href="/"> 

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Prompt:300,200' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="http://localhost/OliwkaFinal/back/Images/default/favicon.png">

</head>
<body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/pl_PL/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.7&appId=1025977917520637";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<app-root><img class="loading-image" src="http://localhost/OliwkaFinal/back/Images/default/loading.gif"></app-root>

</body>
</html>
```

and e.g. app.component.ts (which has the Facebook Page plugin):

```ts
<router-outlet></router-outlet>

<div id="facebook-page-container" *ngIf="!fanpageClosed">
    <a (click)="closeFacebookFanpage()" class="pointer facebook-close-link"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></a>
    <div class="fb-page" 
        data-href="https://www.facebook.com/oliffffffka/" 
        data-tabs="timeline" 
        data-width="250" 
        data-height="420" 
        data-small-header="true" 
        data-adapt-container-width="true" 
        data-hide-cover="true" 
        data-show-facepile="true">
        <blockquote cite="https://www.facebook.com/oliffffffka/" class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore">
            <a href="https://www.facebook.com/oliffffffka/">Oliffffffka</a>
        </blockquote>
    </div>
</div>
```

I was thinking about something like this one:

```ts
facebookLoaded = false;

constructor(private _fbService: FacebookService) {}

ngOnInit(){
    this._fbService.loaded().subscribe(
        response => {
            if(response[state] == "loaded") { // OR true or whatever...
                this.facebookLoaded = true;
            }
        }
    );
}
```

and implementing it in HTML with `*ngIf="facebookLoaded"` on my facebook's plugin tags. Is there a similar way or any way to do this?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Facebook developer [site](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/v2.8/)

```
var finished_rendering = function() {
console.log("finished rendering plugins");
}
// In your onload handler
FB.Event.subscribe('xfbml.render', finished_rendering);
```

and the Facebook plugin html have data-attribute for notify the state, see if you can use that also
**loading**
[image] 
**Rendered** 
[image]
using the above state you may try following css

```
 [fb-xfbml-state="rendered"]{
        display:block;
    }
    [fb-xfbml-state="parsed"]{
        display:none;
    }
```

Comment: CSS doesn't work as expected but the subscriber worked great. Thank you!